# Conditional views exposed filters (using Search api views)

Tags: views

I have two views exposed filters,one dropdown field and a checkbox.
I want,when the checkbox is checked the dropdown field to dissappear.When I uncheck the checkbox I want the dropdown field to appear again.

First I tried Views dependent filter,however it doesn't play well with Search api views.

Secondly I tried with javascript.I wrote this code and added it to the .js file of my theme.However it doesn't also work.How can I do this?

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cdgi = {
    attach: function(context) {

      var $('#edit-field-level-of-telecommuting-1').prop('checked') = true;
      if ($('#edit-field-level-of-telecommuting-1').prop('checked') === true) {
        $('#edit-field-job-region-parents-all').hide();
      } else {
        $('#edit-field-job-region-parents-all').show();
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery));`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem using this code:

```
$('your selects class or id').change(function(){    
if($(this).val() == "publish_on"){
    $('.secret').fadeIn();
}
else{
    $('.secret').hide();
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight change in the code.May be this can help you.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.cdgi = {
    attach: function(context) {
     $(function () {
      $('#edit-field-level-of-telecommuting-1').click(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
          $('#edit-field-job-region-parents-all').hide();
        } else {
          $('#edit-field-job-region-parents-all').show();
        }
      });
     });
    }
  }
}(jQuery));`
```

check more info [how to include js file](https://www.drupal.org/node/304255)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I tried this but still no luck.I have added this on the .js file of my theme,shall I add something else to the theme?

Comment: i have edited the code.if you added the file correctly, i think it will work. try it and if not work let me know how did you add the file?

Comment: I have pasted your code to the end of the cloudy.js file(the js file of my theme).I tried it,cleared caches but still no luck.Shall I do something more?thanks

Comment: it is working fine in my case. Please be sure the file is calling in the page